# intellij - not stopping on all breakpoints in multithreaded code

Tags: multithreading, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am trying to run the following code with break points as follows:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting"); //breakpoint here
        }
    }).start();

    int i = 10;
    i++; //breakpoint here
```

when this code runs ONLY the i++ breakpoint is hit... If I remove that one, the other thread's breakpoint would be hit correctly. Why is this weird behaviour occuring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is documented in http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/breakpoints-2.html:

> There are certain cases when IntelliJ IDEA will not stop at a breakpoint. Consider the following situation:
>   Two breakpoints are set at the different methods of a class, and there suspend policy is set to All.
>   When one of the breakpoints is hit, some step actions are performed.
>   If at the time of stepping another thread hits the second breakpoint, IntelliJ IDEA will not stop there.

I copied your code example and recreated the situation.
Sure enough, like it says in the documentation, after stopping at the `i++` breakpoint, if I hit F8 (step over) the program doesn't stop on the other breakpoint. But if I hit F9 (resume) the program **does** stop again on the other breakpoint.

Comment: I personally believe this is a race condition.  In my case *resume* still does **not** trigger the breakpoint on the new thread.  The only way to fix is to not break right before starting a new thread.  Then it all works.

Comment: Is the suspend policy on your breakpoints set to 'All' (as opposed to 'Thread')?

Comment: Yes they all are.  I can trigger the issue simply by moving the breakpoint closer/further from the thread start, so that alone confirms a race condition of some sort.

Comment: Resume does not work for me.  Breakpoints are all set to `All` and if I hit one breakpoint and then `Resume` (not step) my breakpoints on other threads are not hit.  The test runs to completion without ever seeing the code in the other threads getting hit despite them being on the main code path (primary test runner thread).  As with others, if I remove the breakpoints Ih ave in background threads then the main code path breakpoints are hit.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this problem and for the sake of others that run into this, here is the reason for this behavior and how to change it.

As Doron pointed out, there is documentation concerning this. However, the **IMPORTANT** thing to notice is that by default, all threads in the JVM are suspended when a breakpoint is reached.

What you are expecting (and what I was expecting) is that only the thread with the breakpoint is suspended.

This isn't what you want, nor is it what I wanted.

To change this behavior (and provide the desired behavior).

1) Create a breakpoint by left clicking in margin.
2) Press ctrl+shift+F8 (to bring up the breakpoint menu).
3) Select your breakpoint. You will see options for it.
4) Make sure "Suspend" is checked and "Thread" radio option is selected.
5) Click the "Make default" button.

Now, when you run, you'll see that breakpoints in different threads are hit.

Answer (score 0):

Because the other thread is *scheduled* to run in the background, and when the OS thread scheduler decides to run it, it will run. When you do have a breakpoint in it, it will be hit.

It won't have started necessarily when you just run through the code, so the breakpoint at `i++` is hit immediately.

Comment: The breakpoint is NEVER hit... the main thread finishes executing, I can see the "Starting" string printed, so the line has executed, but no breakpoint was hit